# Tag request: benchmark (or: benchmark-workout)

Tags: feature-request

A '**benchmark**' tag would be appropriate when discussing workout routines that focus on measuring performance. Doing [a search on benchmark](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=benchmark), 25 questions/answers are found (examples: [[1](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9913/what-is-a-good-time-to-row-10-000m-on-a-concept-c2-rowing-machine?s=5|0.0915), [2](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6438/what-is-the-official-baseline-workout-of-crossfit/6439?s=7|0.0875#6439), [3](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16660/how-does-one-get-past-mental-running-barriers/16668?s=12|0.0611#16668), [4](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/any-social-website-for-sharing-and-tracking-fitness-workouts/9404?s=1|0.1790#9404)]) which is comparable to a lot of other tags that seem relevant. Subjects that might be relevant to tag with 'benchmark':

- Benchmark workouts in Crossfit,
- Performance benchmarks when running,
- Fitness tracking (devices, social networks).

One argument against this tag is that it may be too broad. An alternative could be '**benchmark-workout**' as this is something one may want to discuss in particular.